# list username and SIP number for users Asterisk

Tags: linux, shell, sh, asterisk

I have installed Asterisk and i have the file users.conf 
 I want to create a shell script that can `list the usernames and their SIP number`

The users are listed in the file as shown below:

```
[6001]              
type=friend          
host=dynamic            
dtmfmode=rfc2833        
disallow=all            
allow=ulaw          
fullname = John DOE      
username = jdoe         
secret=secret           
context = work
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some simple regexp for this:

```
grep -E '\[[0-9]+\]|username' users.conf
```

Is this output ok? You can also list these without the brackets, or the username = part. If you need more help add a comment

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 asterisk -rx "sip show users"
```

After that if needed rewrite output using sed command.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^\[/h;/^username/!d;G;s/.*= *\(.*\)\n.\(.*\)\]/\1: \2/' users.conf
```

- `/^\[/h` - Copy line beginning with `[` (SIP number) to hold space.
- `/^username/!d` - If line doesn't begin with `username`, delete it and go to next.
  Otherwise (username line):
- `G` - Append hold space (holding SIP number) to username line.
- `s/.*= *\(.*\)\n.\(.*\)\]/\1: \2/` - Extract username and number from combined line and reassemble them in desired output format.